# javascript module pattern from You don't know JS

Tags: javascript, module, callback

I have been reading and testing below code out for several hours now and I just can't seem to grasp certain things.
I have been stepping through chrome console basically putting break in every line I can add and have been inspecting and I am just not sure of things

1)I am just not sure of the purpose of deps array. First odd thing to me is , why doesn't script try to put data on first call to it(from `MyModules.define("bar",[],function()`) ?
  Why does script make second call to `define(MyModules.define("foo",["bar"], function(bar)`) and then add ["bar"] to the array when first define should have done it in the first place?

2)This code `modules[name] = impl.apply(impl,deps)`.    Each callbacks, do not use 'this'.. so was apply necessary here? Also, this is probably my lack of understanding in callback when 'apply' is used, but how does one read this? I thought 'apply' typically goes
         `functionName.apply(obj,[])`

In this case, is this almost like saying
      `functionName.apply(functionName, []) ??`
Or is this different because function itself is anonymous?

```
    var MyModules = (function Manager() {
        var modules = {};

        function define(name,deps,impl) {
            for ( var i=0; i<deps.length; i++) {
                deps[i] = modules[deps[i]];
            }
            modules[name] = impl.apply(impl,deps);
        }

        function get(name) {
            return modules[name];
        }

        return {
            define : define,
            get: get
        };
    })();

    MyModules.define("bar",[],function() {
        function hello(who) {
            return "Let me introduce: " + who;
        }

        return {
            hello : hello
        };
    })

    MyModules.define("foo",["bar"], function(bar) {
        var hungry = "hippo";

        function awesome() {
            console.log(bar.hello(hungry).toUpperCase() );
        }

        return {
            awesome: awesome
        };
    });

    var bar = MyModules.get("bar");
    var foo = MyModules.get("foo");

    console.log(bar.hello("hippo"));

    foo.awesome();
```

Comment: Whoa, this is really confusing, it mixes the *module pattern*  with a dependency management system for modules…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I am just not sure of the purpose of `deps` array.

You seem to be confused on the purpose of the whole `MyModules` object, don't you?

The `define` method can be used to *declare a module*, with a name, an array of dependencies, and a factory function:

- The `name` is the string under which the module object will be stored in that `modules` dictionary
- The `deps` array contains the names of the modules on which the currently declared module depends on.
- The `impl` function will be called to create the module object that will be available under the `name`. It does get passed the module objects to which the names in the `deps` array were resolved.

> Why doesn't script try to put data on first call to it (from `MyModules.define("bar",[],function()`) ? Why does script make second call to define (`MyModules.define("foo",["bar"], function(bar)`)?

It means to declare a module with the name `bar` without any dependencies, and to declare a module with the name `foo` that depends on `bar`. Typically, these two declarations would be placed in different scripts.

> This code `modules[name] = impl.apply(impl,deps)` - Each callbacks, do not use 'this'.. so was apply necessary here?

Yes, [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is necessary here to pass arbitrary many arguments to the function. However, passing the `impl` function for the `this` value does indeed not make any sense, `null` would be more appropriate here.

A better and more understandable definition would be

```
function define(moduleName, dependencyNames, factory) {
    var dependencies = [];
    for (var i=0; i<dependencyNames.length; i++) {
        dependencies[i] = get(dependencyNames[i]); // resolve name
    }
    modules[moduleName] = factory.apply(null, dependencies);
}
```

Comment: I need more time to go over this.   This is very difficult for me to grasp. For an example, I still do not understand why function define cannot just do modules[name] = impl.apply(impl,deps)  ?? Stuffing stuff into deps[] seems unncessary.. no?

Comment: @user3502374: Have a look at *what* it is stuffing in there. My rewritten snippet that actually uses two arrays for this purpose may shed further light on it.

Comment: I think I got it.. I looked at your code and also in 2nd MyModules.define, I replace bar w/ barX(2 of them) and verify that code runs same(so that dependency I assume, meaning second MyModules.define runs with 'this' as 'bar'). I still do not understand the point of code being convoluted to make this work(assuming there is a point behind this that which hasn't hit me home as of yet).  I need to look at this further to really make it mine But I DEFINITELY much appreciated your help!. thank you.

Comment: No, the second module definition doesn't run with the `"bar"` module as `this`, but as the `bar` parameter - it's passed in as the first argument.

Comment: I definitely have to dig deeper.. I also naively hard coded var bar with 'bar' and try not to depend on deps but looks likt that fails.

Comment: "However, passing the impl function for the this value does indeed not make any sense, null would be more appropriate here." It's not a mistake, it's on purpose. I want the `this` in that definition call to predictably be something, regardless of whether they're in strict mode or not. In non-strict mode, passing `null` means `this` points to the global, which is bad. I bind the `this` to the function object itself so that it contains (prevents escape) of any errant `this` assignments in a predictable way.

Comment: @KyleSimpson: Ah, interesting, though such a technique should've been accompanied by an explanation (comment) :-)

Comment: I didn't expect readers to dig into those sorts of nuances. That was my mistake. I will be more careful with updates in future editions of the book. :)