# You don't know JS - module loader

Tags: javascript, module

Im reading "You don't know JS" (1st edition) on github and i'm playing arround with the module loader example from chapter 5. But there are two things, that i don't understand. I found another question here for the same module loader ([javascript module pattern from You don't know JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332645/javascript-module-pattern-from-you-dont-know-js)), but it does not answers my questions.

First the original code:

```
var MyModules = (function Manager() {
    var modules = {};

    function define(name, deps, impl) {
        for (var i=0; i<deps.length; i++) {
            deps[i] = modules[deps[i]];
        }
        modules[name] = impl.apply( impl, deps );
    }

    function get(name) {
        return modules[name];
    }

    return {
        define: define,
        get: get
    };
})();



MyModules.define( "bar", [], function(){
    function hello(who) {
        return "Let me introduce: " + who;
    }

    return {
        hello: hello
    };
} );        // module["bar"] = hello(who) & deps = []

MyModules.define( "foo", ["bar"], function(bar){
    var hungry = "hippo";

    function awesome() {
        console.log( bar.hello( hungry ).toUpperCase() );
    }

    return {
        awesome: awesome
    };
} );        // module["foo"] = awesome() & deps = [hello(who)]



var bar = MyModules.get( "bar" );
var foo = MyModules.get( "foo" );



console.log(
    bar.hello( "hippo" )
);      // Let me introduce: hippo

foo.awesome();  // LET ME INTRODUCE: HIPPO
```

Now the questions:

- Why is **impl** applied to itself (plus the deps object)? I used [w3schools/apply()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp) for looking at how apply() works. There is in the 1st example just an object applied to a function, and not the function itself plus an object.

```
modules[name] = impl.apply( impl, deps );
```

- Why should i give **bar** as a function argument in the definition of foo, since it is in the global scope (also in strict mode)?

```
MyModules.define( "foo", ["bar"], function(bar){
```

If i delete **impl** an **bar** it works like the original code.

```
"use strict";
...
modules[name] = impl.apply( deps );
...
MyModules.define( "foo", ["bar"], function(){
...
```

Are these two things unnecessary or is it a coincidence, that the code works?

Comment: "*Are these two things unnecessary or is it a coincidence, that the code works?*" you've drastically changed the semantics of the module loader but them changed the semantics of the module definition to match it. So, it's not a "coincidence" that it works, but I wouldn't say the code is "unnecessary".

Comment: Change `var bar = MyModules.get( "bar" );` to `var xyz = ...` and your code will no longer run. I suggest looking at how [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) works, it should answer most of your questions

Comment: Oh my question seems so stupid, that is has been downvoted. I used https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp for looking at how apply() works. There is in the 1st example just an object applied to a function, and not the function itself plus an object.

Comment: And for the 2nd thing, i do not understand, why i should give **bar** as a function argument in the definition of foo, since it is in the global scope (also in strict mode).

Comment: "*since it is in the global scope*" what if it isn't? Modules are usually separated so they don't muck around with the global scope. Just because *this* example by virtue of being an example shows usage where you can avoid this, doesn't mean that it's true for the general case.

Comment: I will specify the original question (add the questions from my comments)...

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, i understand. That was indeed stupid. But what about the apply()  applying impl to itself?

Comment: @biberman when you call `apply` the *first* argument is the `this` value for the executed function. In a lot of cases, it doesn't matter what that value is - you can also pass `null` if you don't care about it. However, this module loader passes the *module being loaded*. It's also a sound decision, since *if* `this` is used inside, it's at least something sensible - not the global object, and not `null` which might cause an error. If `this` isn't ised, then it doesn't matter what the value is.

Comment: Also probably worth noting that if you do `this.foo = "hello"` inside the module, it gets attached it to the function. Since a module would only really be ran once, that is fine  - you can read and write properties without much worry that they'd be trampled over

Comment: Thanks again @VLAZ, now i got it. I would like to mark it as the accepted answer...

Comment: @VLAZ: please convert the two comments ("since it is..." and "@biberman...") to an answer, that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is **impl** applied to itself (plus the deps object)? I used [w3schools/apply()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp) for looking at how apply() works. There is in the 1st example just an object applied to a function, and not the function itself plus an object.

Check out [`Function#apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) on MDN. Usually MDN is has more information, so it's worth using it for reference.

When you call `apply()` the first argument is the `this` value for the executed function. In a lot of cases, it doesn't matter what that value is - you can also pass `null` if you don't care about it.

```js
const thisValue = {foo: 3};

function usingThis() {
  return this.foo + 2;
}

console.log(usingThis.apply(thisValue)); // 3 + 2 = 5

function notUsingThis() { 
  return 8;
}

console.log(notUsingThis.apply(thisValue)); // 8
console.log(notUsingThis.apply(null));      // 8
```

However, this module loader passes the module being loaded. It's also a sound decision, since *if* `this` is used inside, it's at least something sensible - not the global object, and not `null` which might cause an error. If `this` isn't used, then it doesn't matter what the value is.

Also probably worth noting that since the value of `this` is the function itself, you use `this.foo = "hello"` inside the module, it gets attached it to the function object. Since a module would only be ran once, that is fine - you can read and write properties without much worry that they'd be trampled over.

> Why should i give **bar** as a function argument in the definition of foo, since it is in the global scope (also in strict mode)?

The reason is that the module loaded and the modules it loads might not be in the same scope. Indeed, if the modules *could* safely reference each other, then you wouldn't need to "load" them, at all as they have all dependencies ready.

However, over time that leads to very hard to track down dependencies and brittle codebase. Not knowing what each module uses is a bad design in the long term.

If you look around at other module systems, they all make declaring dependencies *explicit*: CommonJS, Asynchronous module definition (AMD), as well as the ES6 modules all do the same thing. The module loader shown does a very similar thing.

The example is simplified for illustration purposes. Yes, *in that case* and *that case only*, you can skip the explicit declaration of dependencies. However, in a real code base, modules are likely to be defined in different places without having access to the same scope to keep things from getting messy. That is when the module loader's current design makes perfect sense.